# Triggering A Script When New Mail Arrives

Tags: php, email, imap

I want to run a php script (*for example mail.php*) when anyone send a mail to **go@domain.com** . And then i will get sender, mail body and other informations, and i will use them on *mail.php**.

I read a few articles about getting mails via PHP's IMAP functions. 
I can write a script which checks mail box every second (via cronjobs) and send unread mail's datas to **mail.php** .But i don'T want to do it via cronjobs.

Can i trigger **mail.php** script when someone send an email to **go@domain.com**, automatically ?

(recently i have a reseller account on a linux server (it's allowing IMAP). But i can bought a server (dedicated, vps, cloud etc.) if I really need it.)

Comment: Are you on a dedicated server or VPS? Describe your environment.

Comment: recently i'm using a reseller. But i can bought a server if we need it.

Comment: Assjming it's a unix-based host, you can use a .forward file in that account's home directory to automatically pipe incoming email to a script.

Comment: @Marc B , i need more details.

Comment: some examples here: http://www.activecampaign.com/support/tt/kb/article/help-desk/version-25x-26x/setting-up-supporttrio/setting-up-your-server-to-forward-email-to-the-pipe-script

Comment: @Marc B, thank you. I'm done it ! Now i'm piping **go@domain.com** and it's working very well. But how can i get informations about coming mail ? (sender, body, etc...) ?

Comment: the full email will be given to the script you're piping to, so it's just a matter of extracting the information.

Comment: @Marc B, Will i use STDIN for read mail ?

Comment: Yes. Piped data always goes out via stdout and in via stdin.

Comment: ok @Marc B thank you very much. Can you write your all comments as an answer ? So, i can accept it as accepted answer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's a unix-based host, you can have a .forward file in that account's home directory pipe the email directly to a script. This script would read the email via its STDIN and then go from there.

Some examples shown here: http://www.activecampaign.com/support/tt/kb/article/help-desk/version-25x-26x/setting-up-supporttrio/setting-up-your-server-to-forward-email-to-the-pipe-script

Comment: New url: http://support.helponclick.com/kb/article/help-desk/version-25x-26x/setting-up-supporttrio/setting-up-your-server-to-forward-email-to-the-pipe-script